# Sql code help in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: sql

I'm new to visual studio 2008 and sql, little under 2 weeks now.  Was hoping someone can help clean up my code.  This is a large database and can pull back 6000+ pages.  This code works with smaller call backs but on the larger ones hangs.

```
SELECT   vRTCAttStatusDaily.yr_cde,   
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.trm_cde,   
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.crs_cde,
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.clean_crs_cde,   
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.id_num,   
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.firstname,   
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.lastname,   
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.middlename,   
         name_master.first_name,   
         name_master.last_name,   
         address_master.phone,   
         stud_term_sum_div.udef_1a_1,   
         table_detail.table_desc,   
         vrtcreauthorizationstatus.authorization_status,   
         section_master.division_cde,   
         degree_history.major_1,   
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.StartDate,  
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.cleanclassdate,
         vRTCAttStatusDaily.attend_status,
     stud_term_sum_div.id_num AS id_num2



    FROM {oj vRTCAttStatusDaily LEFT OUTER JOIN vrtcreauthorizationstatus ON vRTCAttStatusDaily.id_num = vrtcreauthorizationstatus.id_num LEFT OUTER JOIN section_master ON vRTCAttStatusDaily.yr_cde = section_master.yr_cde AND vRTCAttStatusDaily.trm_cde = section_master.trm_cde AND vRTCAttStatusDaily.crs_cde = section_master.crs_cde},   
         faculty_load_table,   
         name_master,   
         address_master,   
         stud_term_sum_div,   
         table_detail,   
         degree_history

   WHERE ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.yr_cde = faculty_load_table.yr_cde ) and  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.trm_cde = faculty_load_table.trm_cde ) and  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.crs_cde = faculty_load_table.crs_cde ) and  
         ( faculty_load_table.instrctr_id_num = name_master.id_num ) and  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.id_num = stud_term_sum_div.id_num ) and  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.yr_cde = stud_term_sum_div.yr_cde ) and  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.trm_cde = stud_term_sum_div.trm_cde ) and  
         ( stud_term_sum_div.udef_1a_1 = table_detail.table_value ) and  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.id_num = address_master.id_num ) and  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.id_num = degree_history.id_num ) and  
         ( ( faculty_load_table.lead_instrctr_flg = 'Y' ) AND  
         ( address_master.addr_cde = '*LHP' ) AND  
         ( table_detail.column_name = 'rtc_enroll_sts' ) AND  
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.yr_cde IN (@Year)) AND 
         ( vRTCAttStatusDaily.trm_cde IN (@Term)) AND
           degree_history.cur_degree = 'Y' )

ORDER BY address_master.id_num,
     vRTCAttStatusDaily.startdate,
     vRTCAttStatusDaily.clean_crs_cde
```

Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: stackoverflow is for relatively short programming problems, you should post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: do you need to fetch so many rows at once ? If not, you can use `SELECT TOP x` where `x` is count of the rows to fetch. Since we don't know your DB structure, server etc. it's impossible to give you any suggestion.

Comment: Will do thanks. daemon that might be useful I look into it futher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out the code written for vrtcattstatusdaily called on itself basically twice. Not much I could do about that, but removing faculty_table_load from the query made it work properly. It now can pull 289k rows in roughly 1.4 mins. Thanks Biggs

Here is the thread when it was moved to codereview https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/sql-code-help-in-visual-studio-2008